# Date and include time to countdown using javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying below code for countdown to on exact date and time. I mean, i wants to make a under contractions website countdown date (include exact time). but date are not count downing. js code just showed me wrong count and not downing second, min, hours, day. This js code has problem, but i don't understand, exactly where is the problem.

Here is code:

```
(function init() {
  function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date("03/13/2018 9:30 AM"));
    var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
    var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    return {
      'total': t,
      'days': days,
      'hours': hours,
      'minutes': minutes,
      'seconds': seconds
    };
  }

  function initializeClock(endtime){
  var timeinterval = setInterval(function(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    document.querySelector(".days > .value").innerText=t.days;
    document.querySelector(".hours > .value").innerText=t.hours;
    document.querySelector(".minutes > .value").innerText=t.minutes;
    document.querySelector(".seconds > .value").innerText=t.seconds;
    if(t.total<=0){
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  },1000);
}
initializeClock(((new Date()).getFullYear()+1) + "/1/1")
})();
```

Comment: Why are you hard coding the start Date, the start Date should be the current date time

Comment: so, i have to write code like this: `var end = new Date("here is my date and time using space")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some modifications to your code.

I added a `displayTime()` function that handles the time display.

`initializeClock()` now calls `displayTime()` directly when it's called, without waiting one second.

`getTimeRemaining()` now calculates the right time, by taking the current date into account, and not a random date: `var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());`

```js
function displayTime(date){
  var t = getTimeRemaining(date);
  document.querySelector(".days > .value").innerText = t.days;
  document.querySelector(".hours > .value").innerText = t.hours;
  document.querySelector(".minutes > .value").innerText = t.minutes;
  document.querySelector(".seconds > .value").innerText = t.seconds;
  return t;
}

function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(endtime) {
  displayTime(endtime);
  
  var timeinterval = setInterval(function() {
    t = displayTime(endtime);
    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
initializeClock("2018/03/13 09:30")
```

```html
<div class="days"><span class="value"></span> days</div>
<div class="hours"><span class="value"></span> hours</div>
<div class="minutes"><span class="value"></span> minutes</div>
<div class="seconds"><span class="value"></span> seconds</div>
```

Comment: its working. thanks. but i wants to set date. example: `03/12/2018 - 03/13/2018`

Comment: @Jemspoole What do you mean you want to set the date? In order to have a countdown, you have to take the current date into account.

Comment: current date to countdown finished date. count down will be finished after my selected date

Comment: @Jemspoole That's already what's happening with `initializeClock(((new Date()).getFullYear() + 1) + "/1/1")`, just change it to what you want.

Comment: @Jemspoole  `initializeClock("2018/03/13 09:30")` please note dates really should be initialised using ISO format, .. `YYYY/MM/DD`

Comment: already i tried this `initializeClock("2018/03/13 09:30")` but showing me full year count down.

Comment: @Jemspoole As you can see in the snippet I edited, `initializeClock("2018/03/13 09:30")` works.

Comment: oh sorry... its working. My browser history has problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this overly complicated. If you just start with a date and then every second, subtract one second from that start date, you're done.

```js
var out = document.getElementById("output");
var start = new Date();
setInterval(function(){
  start = new Date(start.getTime() - 1000);
  out.textContent =
    start.getHours() + " Hours, " + start.getMinutes() + " Minutes, " + start.getSeconds() + " Seconds";
},1000);
```

```html
<div>Counting down from current time</div>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: Not quite @Keith. `setTimeout` and `setInterval` can't be relied on to fire at exactly their designated intervals/timers, but when the code runs, it will always get the current time and work from that. So, the time won't be wrong, but the frequency with which it gets updated just can't be guaranteed to be every exact second. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) would be better for this, but that's not really what the question was about.

Comment: Hi Scott, setInterval can drift and miss a callback.  And your code is subtracting 1 second each time, if you alter to work out the difference each time it would be fine.